# Android listview not showing on real device

Tags: android, listview

My listview works well in virtual device. When I tried to test on real device, my listview not showing anything.

Here my list xml code.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:background="#FAFAFA" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lacci_list"
        android:divider="#E8E8E8"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here my row xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FAFAFA">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:text="lacci"
        android:id="@+id/lacci_row"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove all the text color and background color from your XML file and see if that works. If that works, try to use appropriate color combinations

Comment: @Nabin It doesn't works.